# Tokenized output of C source code

Tags: c, compiler-construction, tokenize

I want to look at the tokenized output my c-source code. The cpp processor first process the cpp-directives and then it tokenizes the c source code. Then the this tokenized output is parsed.

After that assembler does the job and process continues.

I have written my tokenizer using flex. I just want to see how gcc compiler tokenizes c source code.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking; can you rephrase?

Comment: In the documentation of the GNU preprocessor, it is written that the c source code is tokenized. Ex 2+3 is tokenized as Int(2) PLUS Int(3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC can output the result of the preprocessing step, and there is another option (intended for debugging the preprocessor) to show you details of the tokens:

```
gcc  -E  -fdebug-cpp  yourinpufile.c
```

Comment: I believe that the code of the c-tokenizer must have been written in flex, as flex and bison are used in GCC. Can I get the source code of the c-tokenizer? I want to understand how does gcc compiler works.